# How do I login to a deployed Virtual Machine in Azure?

Tags: server, juju

Mongo DB service is deployed in a Azure Virtual machine Using Ubuntu Juju. How to Login to the newly created Virtual Machine?

Answer (score 5):

In your terminal run:

```
juju status
```

Locate the machine name and then ssh into it using:

```
juju ssh <serviceName>/<machineNumber>
```

ex:

```
juju ssh mongodb/0
```

You can get a list of all of the juju commands using:

```
juju help commands
```

To get help on a specific command run:

```
juju help <command>
```

Comment: I want to allocate the newly deployed virtual machine to the end user. Is it possible to login directly to the newly created Virtual Machine ??

Comment: Yes that's exactly what my answer explains how to do.

Comment: Did you mean log into some web ui running on the newly created virtual machine? If so then you will need to expose that virtual machine to the world using `juju expose <serviceName>` which will open up the ports defined in the charm.